# Using Priority Queue with Custom Comparator to Sort Based on Number of Words in a String?

Tags: java, string, sorting, priority-queue, cpu-word

I'm trying to use Priority Queue to sort strings based on how many words (white spaces) there are in each string. My code works only in certain scenerios, but not when the amount of white spaces per string is really spread out. I think because my methods aren't comparing them all.

```
Comparator<String> whiteSpaces = new Comparator<String>() {
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        char c = ' ';
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                if(s1.charAt(i) == c){
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
                if(s2.charAt(i) == c) {
                    count2++;
                }
            }
            return count1 - count2;
        }
    };
```

Could I modify what I have so that it compares to all the strings added to the priorityqueue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is not working as you expect?

Comment: There's a difference between the number of words and the number of spaces. For example, the string "hello_happy_world" has three words and two spaces (treat the underline characters as spaces. The string "hello____world" has two words and four spaces. If you sort based on number of spaces, you aren't sorting on number of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Comparator` isn't working because you don't reset `count1` and `count2` to `0` between calls to `compare()`.

Actually, the problem is that `count1` and `count2` are fields. They should be local variables.

Move `count1` and `count2` declarations into the method.

```
Comparator<String> whiteSpaces = new Comparator<String>() {
    char c = ' ';
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            if(s1.charAt(i) == c){
                count1++;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            if(s2.charAt(i) == c) {
                count2++;
            }
        }
        return count1 - count2;
    }
};
```

Other improvements:

- Field `c` should be `private` and `final`, and better named.
- Create a helper method to eliminate repeated code.
- Use `Integer.compare(a, b)` instead of subtraction.

```
Comparator<String> whiteSpaces = new Comparator<String>() {
    private final char separator = ' ';
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(countSeparators(s1), countSeparators(s2));
    }
    private int countSeparators(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == separator) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

Comment: Oneliner: `Comparator<String> whiteSpaces = Comparator.comparingLong(s -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == ' ').count())`